# LinearRegressor.train() throughs "...is not a callable object" exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, lambda

I am new to TensorFlow and I am not very experienced in Python. I am learning with the following tutorial:

[First steps with tensor flow](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/first_steps_with_tensor_flow.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=firststeps-colab&hl=en)

If I use lambda to define the input function (as it is explained in the tutorial), everything works fine:

```
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None) : 
    ...
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels

_=linear_regressor.train(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(my_feature, targets), steps=100)
```

if I change the script as follows:

```
def get_my_input_fn() :
    def my_input_func(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None) :
        ...
        features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        return features, labels
    return my_input_func

temp_my_input_fn=get_my_input_fn()
_=linear_regressor.train(input_fn=temp_my_input_fn(my_feature, targets), steps=100)
```

I receive an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 1126, in getfullargspec
    sigcls=Signature)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 2193, in _signature_from_callable
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a callable object'.format(obj))
TypeError: ({'MeanHHInc': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>}, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(?,) dtype=int64>) is not a callable object
```

In both cases `my_input_function()` receives the same arguments and returns the same tuple `(<class 'dict'>, <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>)` (saw in the debugger).

What do I do wrong when I use the second approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_fn=temp_my_input_fn(my_feature, targets)
```

would assign the value of computing the function to `input_fn` and therefore it is no longer a callable object.

Check the below example to see the difference

```
>>> def getfunc():
...     def square(x):
...             return x**2
...     return square
...
>>> d = getfunc()

>>> def test(fn = None):
...     return fn(x)
...
>>> x = 2
>>>
>>> test(fn=d(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> test(fn=d)
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
In your code you assigned `x = 2` before you call `test(fn=d)` and it works.
when I tried to do pretty much same:
`temp_my_input_fn=get_my_input_fn()
features=my_feature1
targets=targets1
_=linear_regressor.train(input_fn=temp_my_input_fn, steps=100)`
it threw following exception: TypeError: my_input_func() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'features' and 'targets'

Comment: set ```features=my_feature1 targets=targets1``` before the other definitions.

Comment: you can play around the repl and see the impact of when you define x in the example i provided.

Comment: In your example x must be defined before `test(fn=d)`. If not - it threw exception: NameError: name 'x' is not defined. In my case the error is a bit different. I am trying to understand what it means now. But thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Found solution for the last problem. It could be solved as follow - declaring functions: `def get_my_input_fn(features1, targets1) :
    def my_input_func(features=features1, targets=targets1, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None) :` and calling functions: `temp_my_input_fn=get_my_input_fn()` (sorry formatting for the code is a little off)

Answer (score 0):

Below code sample will solve this callable error:

```
def get_my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None) :
  def my_input_fn():
    """Trains a linear regression model of one feature.

    Args:
      features: pandas DataFrame of features
      targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
      batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
      shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data.
      num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = repeat indefinitely
    Returns:
      Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
    """
    nonlocal features, targets, batch_size, shuffle, num_epochs

    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays.
    features = {key:np.array(value) for key,value in dict(features).items()}                                           

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating.
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified.
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels
  return my_input_fn

temp_my_input_fn=get_my_input_fn(my_feature, targets)
_ = linear_regressor.train(input_fn=temp_my_input_fn, steps=100)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I have not enough reputation points to add "usefullness" to your answer.